# Python package installed but content from __init__ isn't importable

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have the following package structure:

```
module_installer/   
|-- module_installer
|   `-- __init__.py 
`-- setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup                             
setup(name='module_installer')
```

**module_installer/__init__.py**

```
class ImportMe():
    pass
```

Being in the "root directory" of the package the class `ImportMe` is importable:

```
module_installer$ tree --charset=ASCI
|-- module_installer
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- setup.py
python -c "from module_installer import ImportMe"
# This makes sense. The current dir is in python path and the `module_installer` has `__init__.py.
```

However if I install it and try to run it from a different directory it fails:

```
module_installer$ pip install .
module_installer$ cd /some_other_dir
some_other_dir$ python -c "from module_installer import ImportMe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImportMe' from 'module_installer' (unknown location)
```

Grepping `pip freeze` for `module-installer` shows the packages successfully installed.

Exploring the package for files doesn't show the package installed:

```
$ pip show -f module-installer
...
Location: /home/user/Envs/se_ena/lib/python3.7/site-packages
...
Files:
  module_installer-0.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  module_installer-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
  module_installer-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
  module_installer-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  module_installer-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
# No traces of module_installer/__init__.py?
```

Doesn't the `__init__.py` get installed correctly and the class isn't importable?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`, and where exactly is the `module_installer` directory?

Comment: @JohnGordon
The `PYTHONPATH` does contain `/home/user/Envs/se_ena/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. And the `module_installer` is my home dir.

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to modify `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`). I would advise to avoid doing such a thing as much as possible, there is almost always a much saner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the `setuptools.setup` function call in `setup.py` is missing the list of packages as an argument to the `packages` parameter.

`setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    packages=['module_installer'],
    # ...
)
```

To avoid listing packages manually, *setuptools* provides the following utility functions:

- [`find_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages)
- [`find_namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages)

Comment: Use `find_packages()` to not have to type names and be future proof if you add more packages.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Did that help answer the question?